# Microservices using .net Framework 4 and above ( instead of .NET Core)

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, microservices, .net-framework-version

I am a .net developer and trying to learn implementing Microservice using .NET Framework >4.0.
All the article that I refer from internet search, they all talks about implementing Microservices using .NET Core.  But I wonder, I could not find any article that says how to develop microservice using .NET Framework >4.0.

I knew that .net core has all the features and run time for Microservices but my question is as below
Question -
1. Is not possible develop Microservice using .NET framework at all ? If not then what are all constrain and limitation ?
2. What are the alternatives if we choose .NET Framework only to develop Microservices oriented architecture
3. Any example/ sample code will be helpful

Thank you

Comment: Microservices is just a set of architectural principles. It doesn't depend on the language that is used to implement these principles.

Comment: A microservice in ASP.Net (.Net Framework) could be implemented using ASP.Net Web API, using HttpClient to initiate requests to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, microservices (MS) is not bound to any language, it's an architectual principle.

> Microservices are a software development technique —a variant of the
>   service-oriented architecture (SOA) structural style— that arranges an
>   application as a collection of **loosely coupled** services. In a
>   microservices architecture, services are **fine-grained and the
>   protocols are lightweight**.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices

You can build MS/SOA with any language and a variety of platform solutions, but there are drawbacks of course to some implementations.

All you do is define a small service A and another small service B to act as your system, exposing data through lightweight REST API(s) (maybe even gRPC) and let them talk to each other - and voila! you have your MS system.

But why are e.g. Microsoft pushing to use .NET Core for MS systems? My best guess would be because of **Docker** (and other container solutions), to containerize each MS. The difference between .NET Core and .NET Framework in this context is containerization, .NET Core can run on all platforms, such as linux - and docker supports linux containers.

> In computing, self-contained system (SCS) is a software architecture
>   approach that focuses on a **separation of the functionality into many
>   independent systems**, making the complete logical system a
>   collaboration of many smaller software systems
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-contained_system_(software)

Why are the linux containers important? Well, I would argue because of **Kubernetes** (or other container orchestration tools).

> Kubernetes (commonly stylized as k8s) is an open-source
>   container-orchestration system for automating **application deployment,
>   scaling, and management**. It was originally designed by Google, and
>   is now maintained by the Cloud Native Computing Foundation. It aims to
>   provide a "platform for automating deployment, scaling, and operations
>   of application containers across clusters of hosts". It works with
>   a range of container tools, including **Docker**. Many cloud services
>   offer a Kubernetes-based platform or infrastructure as a service (PaaS
>   or IaaS) on which Kubernetes can be deployed as a platform-providing
>   service. Many vendors also provide their own branded Kubernetes
>   distributions.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes

Kubernetes is a very powerful container orchestration system. I't can scale your loosely coupled MS linux containers at will - and so much more.

Now, I'd suggest you to keep on reading, a good start would be this:

Read

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/

Source code

- https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers
- https://github.com/EdwinVW/pitstop

Videos

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AfZxdXa7yc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWUINCZHs6E

Comment: Thanks a lot Henkolicious for sharing all those details. It will definitely help me learning MS Oriented Architecture

Comment: @Sam K No worries, let me know if you need any clarifications.